# What permissions make the Notification object field be non-null?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been doing quite a bit of experimentation with reading a user's facebook notifications.

The JSON for a notification returned by the Graph contains an `object` field. My question is: **what permissions does my app need in order for this field to be non-null?**

## Some Background

The problem I'm trying to solve is to give the user an email-like view of their facebook notifications. Rather than only display "A user posted a comment on your post", I want to display the comment itself. Sending a request to `/notifications` will return JSON that has an `object` field:

```
{
  "id": "notif_XXXXXXXX_373403974", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Michael XXXXX", 
    "id": "XXXXXXXX"
  }, 
  "to": {
    "name": "Josaphat Valdivia", 
    "id": "XXXXXXXX"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2013-03-10T19:46:38+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2013-03-10T19:46:38+0000", 
  "title": "Michael XXXXXXX posted in Pie on Pi!: \"I'm assuming cheesecake counts as pie.\"", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/events/119151878267920/123715204478254/", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Events", 
    "id": "141157392619610"
  }, 
  "unread": 0, 
  "object": null
},
```

Unfortunately, this field seems to mostly be `null`. If I grant my app nearly all permissions, though, the field will be populated by what I've come to call the "source object":

```
{
  "id": "notif_XXXXXXX_373368858", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Carly XXXXXX", 
    "id": "XXXXXXX"
  }, 
  "to": {
    "name": "Josaphat Valdivia", 
    "id": "XXXXXXXX"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2013-03-10T15:48:44+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2013-03-10T15:48:44+0000", 
  "title": "Carly XXXXXXX updated her status: \"yes yes concert yesssssssss\"", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX/posts/10151810126992926", 
  "unread": 0, 
  "object": {
    "id": "XXXXXXX_10151810126992926", 
    "from": {
      "name": "Carly XXXXX", 
      "id": "XXXXXXXX"
    }, 
    "message": "yes yes concert yesssssssss", 
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "Comment", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/posts/10151810126992926"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Like", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/posts/10151810126992926"
      }
    ], 
    "privacy": {
      "value": ""
    }, 
    "type": "status", 
    "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
    "created_time": "2013-03-10T15:48:43+0000", 
    "updated_time": "2013-03-10T15:48:43+0000", 
    "likes": {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "Jenna XXXXXXX", 
          "id": "XXXXXXXXX"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Kymberlee XXXXXXXX", 
          "id": "XXXXXXX"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Lori XXXXXX", 
          "id": "XXXXXXX"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Andreas XXXXXXXX", 
          "id": "XXXXXXX"
        }
      ], 
      "count": 6
    }, 
    "comments": {
      "count": 0
    }
  }
},
```

Notice that in this snippet, the `object` field contains all of the information about the post including actions, likes, and comments.

This problem is blowing my mind: experimenting with the Graph Explorer can only take me so far because there are so many possible combinations of permissions that trying every combination would likely take several lifetimes.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: I was getting non-null data just fine until I checked in the graph explorer tonight. Now all of my notifications have null as the "object" field, just like yours.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with permissions, but I have no idea what they are. It also has to do with the post types. Friends posting on events and groups, for example, don't have a post object (regardless of permissions, it seems; though I could be wrong).

Comment: Yeah, I'm messing around in the Graph Explorer and it's almost like there's some combination of permissions you need to have instead of just a single one that'll fill out the "object" field. I'm trying to figure it out now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an odd combination but here are the two permissions (besides `manage_notifications` obviously) I've found that make it work. You have to have both of them.

`user_groups`

`read_stream`

I have no idea what it is about these particular permissions, but trial-and-error led me to that combination.

Comment: I think there's something else at work here (or something has changed over the last year) - my app has both those permissions and I still see `object == null` on all notification objects.

Comment: Unless Facebook added some specifics into the documentation or changed the API (I haven't work with Facebook in a while), then this question is still open.